# Filter JSON object within Fetch [Reactjs]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have this state defined:

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            open: false,
            customers:[],
            customer:{},
            products:[],
            product:{},
            orders:[],
            order:{},
            newForm:true,
            phoneNumbererror:null,
            shop:this.props.salon,
            value:'a',
            showTab:'none',
            slideIndex: 0,

        };
    }
```

With the following function which contains a fetch, I recieve an array of objects with responseData:

```
getProducts(){
        fetch(
            DOMAIN+'/api/products/', {
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization':'Bearer '+this.props.token
                }
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({products:responseData})
                console.log("Console log de products responseData");
                console.log(responseData);
            })
            .catch(function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }
```

This function is called in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount(){
        this.getCustomers();
        this.getProducts();
    }
```

The JSON object obtained from the fetch and kept within `this.state.products` looks like this:

```
Array(72)
0:
brand:{_id: "592d3092f42d775da9d38063", name: "Moroccanoil", __v: 0, created: "2017-05-30T08:42:58.242Z", photos: Array(0)}
created:"2017-06-14T18:46:52.508Z"
description:"Aporta una flexibilidad excepcional y proporciona un look hidratado y mate. Aplica una cantidad igual a la punta del dedo de esta arcilla filtrada, emulsiona entre las manos y distribúyela por el cabello. La fórmula de la arcilla purificada aporta al cabello textura y un acabado ligero y mate, y el Mineral Oil Finishing. Complex le proporciona un aspecto sano."
images:["https://storage.googleapis.com/magnifique-dev/olaplex 3.jpg"]
line:"Pruebadelproductolargo"
name:"Nombremuylargoaversicabe"
price:400
profile:"Decoloración"
salePrice:0
sex:["Mujer"]
size:"100 ML"
stock:400
videos:[""]
__v:19
_id:"5941849ce4fa0c7442b0f885"
__proto__:Object
```

[image]

As shown previously in the fetch, with this line `this.setState({products:responseData})` I can pass `products` to the table where I want `name` and `price` to be displayed:

```
<DataTables
     height={'auto'}
     selectable={false}
     showRowHover={true}
     columns={FAV_TABLE_COLUMNS}
     data={this.state.products}
     showCheckboxes={false}
     rowSizeLabel="Filas por página"
           />
```

The table called is:

```
const FAV_TABLE_COLUMNS = [
    {
        key: 'name',
        label: 'Producto'
    }, {
        key: 'price',
        label: 'Precio del producto'
    }
];
```

**How can I filter the products to display only the favourite ones of the client?**

All of the favourite products of the client are stored in this other object within the array `favouritesProducts`:

```
Array(22)
12:
app:{created: "2017-07-07T13:34:14.249Z"}
billingAddress:[]
cardLastNumbers:"5262"
cardSaved:"true"
created:"2017-06-30T09:51:59.869Z"
creditCard:
cardNumberSalt: 
expirationSalt:
email:"angel@magnifique.club"
eyebrowType:"Pobladas"
eyelashType:"Rectas"
favouritesProducts:
Array(1)
0:
"594186cee4fa0c7442b0f942"
length:1
__proto__:
Array(0)
favouritesServices:[]
hairColor:"Rubio"
hairState:"Dañado"
hairType:"Medio"
loginType:[]
nailPolish:"Semipermanente"
nailType:"Naturales"
name:"AngelFBMag"
payerSaved:"true"
phoneNumber:
pictures:[]
platform:undefined
salt:
sex:"Mujer"
shippingAddress:[{…}]
shop:{_id: "59108159bc3fc645704ba508", location: {…}, settings: {…}, customers: Array(0), __v: 0, …}
surname:"Marquez"
__v:13
_id:"59561f3f1d178e1966142ad7"
__proto__:Object
```

[image]

This object is obtained through this other function:

```
getCustomers(){
        fetch(
            DOMAIN+'/api/customers/shop/'+this.props.salon, {
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization':'Bearer '+this.props.token
                }
            })
            .then((response) =>
            {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((responseData) => {
                responseData.map(function (v) {
                    v.platform = v.app ? v.app.platform : null  })
                this.setState({customers:responseData})
                console.log(responseData);
            })
            .catch(function() {
                console.log("error");
            });
    }
```

Currently I can print all the products without a filter. The question is how can I filter the products that I obtain, with the favourite products of the client. How can I pass the ID of the favourite product stored within the array to the fetch used in getProducts.

Comment: *"The JSON object obtained...looks like this:"* That's not JSON, that's some kind of dump from your console which is very hard to read. Please post the actual JSON.

Comment: Added a capture of the object, sorry.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just added 2 captures of both involved objects.

Comment: I can't post the whole solution, but i guess one easy way is to use `Set` https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Set and its `has` function

Comment: @Okazari So I just checked your suggestion. Would be like favouriteProducts.has("idProduct"); ?

Comment: @Eartair Yeah, probably something like that, i'm not that familiar with Sets, but i know that it does a great job for list intersections (it may even have a function to get the whole intersection in a single call)

Comment: @Okazari I'm neither familiar with Sets. I'll have to study how to implement it correctly.